# Android - Handler repeating task stops executing while the screen is on at Foreground Service

Tags: android, multithreading, foreground-service

First of all, this is a long question but targeting only one topic, and I'm sorry I cannot share any code as it is a project of our company and is classified. We are using a foreground service that executes a task within 100 milliseconds only. Until I asked this question we used multiple approaches on executing a code in a short amount of time, follows:

- A thread with "Thread.sleep" in it (not the best approach but it was our first try, went inconsistent),
- A thread with "Object.wait" (same result as above),
- [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) (also is inconsistent and stops executing after some time),
- [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) which also has the problem of all above.

On my phone (HUAWEI P20 Lite), after trying these approaches, we finally decided to use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) with a [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) as the work does not require to interact with UI thread. (not always but we are using a seperate handler for it.) In between every approach, this seems to be the most consistent one, however we don't know if it depends on the phone, manufacturer or anything, my phone stops executing the looping handler with postDelayed **until I interact with the app UI in some way, for example: touching the notification, while the screen is on.** Yes, I'm not talking about clicking the notification itself, but even touching, or like expanding the detail text starts the handler again. Which means, I think my phone is trying to save power with pausing the background execution.

Now, we only want to run this method while the screen is on, as we are already pausing the handler itself via "a screen on-off broadcast receiver" that registered in the foreground service by removing the callbacks of the runnable, but after screen goes on, broadcast is received but even if "Handler.post()" executes, it does not run the runnable inside, hence it never loops.

To give you a bit of context, this is what kind of logic we are following:

We open a foreground service with something similar to the below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                   MyService.class));
}
else
{
    getApplicationContext().startService(
         new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
}
```

And then, inside the service we do something like the following:

```
public int onStartCommand()
{
    // notification stuff

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("myThread");
    thread.start();

    Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() 
    {
         // do stuff
         // this runnable stops executing after some time. This is where the problem lies.
         handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    })

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The handler inside onStartCommand is unstable, sometimes it does not respect the delay, or sometimes it does not execute at all. Now, not respecting the delay is not the problem as we don't have to be that consistent as our calculations do not depend on the elapsed time or something, but if it stops executing (which in this case, it does), that's where the problem starts.

To handle this, we are going to use a brand new class that Android Jetpack offers, [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/), which is perfect for checking the status of handlers. To understand if the threads are active or not, we registered the last execution time of the code inside the handler and are going to access it via the worker class. Now, if the handlers are down, we would like to wake these handlers up. How can this be done? Because remember, **this happens while the screen is on.**

Edit: Here are some logs about how the thread execution goes.

```
//2018-12-19 11:35:15.048 17222-17952/com.example.something D/MyService: threadName: MainThread, postDelayedValue: true
//2018-12-19 11:35:15.154 17222-17952/com.example.something D/MyService: threadName: MainThread, postDelayedValue: true
2018-12-19 11:35:15.262 17222-17952/com.example.something D/MyService: threadName: MainThread, postDelayedValue: true
2018-12-19 11:35:45.262 17222-17952/com.example.something D/MyService: threadName: MainThread, postDelayedValue: true
//2018-12-19 11:35:45.365 17222-17952/com.example.something D/MyService: threadName: MainThread, postDelayedValue: true
//2018-12-19 11:35:45.468 17222-17952/com.example.something D/MyService: threadName: MainThread, postDelayedValue: true
```

Any suggestions? Any workarounds for this? Every help and comment is appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Not really, the code inside handler stops executing, even if it is on loop.

Comment: There is none. No exception or anything. It just loops for a certain amount of time, then it stops. Afterwards, as I said, if I interact with the notification in any way, it starts looping again, without calling anything, as the device waits for my interaction.

Comment: Haven't checked yet, but I assume it will be false because there is a problem with the actual message. Even though, checking now.

Comment: Just checked, it returns true. Putting some logs to clarify the situation even more. Editing question right now.

Comment: Edited the question with logs. Commented the ones that can be ignored, but the uncommented ones have 30 seconds of delay. The handler started executing again after I touched the notification, as stated.

Comment: Just tried, can confirm that it works the same way.

Comment: It might work, but why we should use UI thread to perform background operations? There has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: As far as I know binding the service is used to call methods from the service from the context that has been used (in this case it will be the main activity) so, I don't think it means anything since main activity dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found where the problem was, it is running smoothly everywhere else except on my device (and probably other devices which has EMUI on their system), which is apparently pretty strict about power management.

Here are the logs:

```
2018-12-19 16:45:52.943 12619-12822/com.example.something D/ThreadHelper: MainThread looping.
2018-12-19 16:45:52.986 1699-2028/? I/ash: com.example.something skips not important notification
2018-12-19 16:45:52.996 1699-2028/? I/ash: com.example.something { doze duration=40061 UptimeDuration=40061 } transition to: hibernation reason:
2018-12-19 16:45:52.996 1699-2028/? I/ash: perform hibernation actions: com.example.something
```

My device, by on it's own, decides that the process with a notification that is not important can be silently stopped, so I increased the importance of the notification with **NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX**. Now, it does not stop working at all.

If you experience something like this and want to assure that raising the notification won't be enough for you, then on HUAWEI devices there is a setting that can be opened with Settings --> Battery --> Launch. Disable your automatic app power management and make it manual, so the OS won't interfere with the process ever (hopefully).

Comment: Can you explain how you increased the importance of the notification?

Comment: @Ryan you can check the documentation for it, but on notification channel above Oreo, you can use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX` and on notification itself you can call `setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)`.

Comment: this post is about handler postDelayed not working after a period of time. I just tried, there is no handler method to set a priority

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen on pre-Oreo devices?

If you start a service with `startForegroundService`, you should immediately call `setForeground` on `onStartCommand`. Otherwise service is killed within a short amount of time.

Also, your handler reference is local to `onStartCommand`, that may be why it does not persist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the code I've given above is just an example. It would already throw an exception if startForeground was not called, but it is not throwing any. About the handler, it is already global, like I said the above is just an example. And, I haven't had the opportunity of testing the code in pre-Oreo devices yet.